# How to interpret the returned string of timeit

Tags: python, timing

The following:

```
timeit print("foo")
```

returns something like: `100000 loops, best of 3: 2.35 µs per loop`. I guess the `100000` relates to `number` argument of `timeit`. I don't understand what is `best of 3` means and what is the time unit in use? In this case it is probably *microsecond*, but I also saw `us` and `ns` as units; however, I could not find an explanation in the documentation.

Answer (score 13):

I'm presuming you are talking about the [Command-line interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#command-line-interface) here.

The command line interface first will try to find a suitable number of tests; it starts with 10 runs, scales that up by a factor of 10 until the total time taken exceeds 0.2 seconds. If it prints *10000 loops*, then that was the number of loops that takes 0.2 seconds or more.

The `3` is the repeat count; the tests are repeated several times, with `--repeat` defaulting to 3. The fastest time of those 3 is then taken.

Then the total time for the fastest run is divided by the test number. The number is presented either in seconds, milliseconds or microseconds, depending on how fast the loop was. There are 1000 microseconds in a millisecond, and 1000 milliseconds in a second, and the unit is printed as `sec`, `msec` and `usec`, respectively.

IPython has their own `%timeit` command based on all this, but they abbreviated further and use `s`, `ms`, `us` and even `ns` if your code was fast enough to require a nanosecond unit size. The `us` microsecond unit can also be displayed as `µs` if your terminal allows it.

You can take a look at the [Python 3.4 implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a18444102268/Lib/timeit.py#l243), and compare it with the [iPython implentation](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/23fb4ff6343e32b9d1921af4f9f1c58ffadd3376/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L897) (with the time display handled by the [`_format_time()` function](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/23fb4ff6343e32b9d1921af4f9f1c58ffadd3376/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L1313).